# Scala refactoring duplicate code

Tags: scala, parsing, code-duplication

I am new to Scala and trying to figure out how to refactor the following code to avoid duplicate functions. As you can see those are very similar and just need refactoring into generic code.

```
    protected lazy val shardNamesSpec: Parser[Seq[String]] = {
        (ident ^^ {case d => Seq(d)}) | ("(" ~> repsep(ident, ",") <~ ")") ^^ {
          case i => i
        }
      }

    protected lazy val shardTypesSpec: Parser[Seq[DataType]] = {
        (dataType ^^ {case d => Seq(d)}) | ("(" ~> repsep(dataType, ",") <~ ")") ^^ {
          case dt => dt
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you need smth like following:

```
  def parseExpr[T](value: Parser[T]): Parser[Seq[T]] = {
    (value ^^ {case d => Seq(d)}) | ("(" ~> repsep(value, ",") <~ ")") ^^ {
      case i => i
    }

  }

  protected lazy val shardNamesSpec: Parser[Seq[String]] = parseExpr(ident)

  protected lazy val shardTypesSpec: Parser[Seq[DataType]] = parseExpr(dataType)
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, but I'm getting compilation errors: 

"value ^^ ..." cannot resolve symbol ^^
cannot resolve symbol |
"repsep" cannot resolve reference repsep with such signature

Comment: I've modified method signature, can you try again? ... and just to double check: your `dataType` extending Parser, is not it?